Why ETFs that replicates the MSCI World LEVERAGED 2X Daily (SHLE) don't seem to exist (yet)?
I am a French young personal investor that took interested in ETF during the pandemic COVID. I have soon started to invest in ETF that follows indices such as the MSCI World, the S&P500 or the Nasdaq-100.
I have recently also started to invest in leveraged ETF such as Nasdaq-100 leveraged daily x2 LQQ) or CL2. CL2 isn't exactly like a S&P500 leveraged daily x2 but SSO is. However, I am very much surprised I could not find any ETF that tracks the MSCI World LEVERAGED 2X Daily (SHLE)?
Have I not searched enough? Is there any reason for that? On the 11th of June 2024, SHLE has a returned of 161% over the last 5 years while the MSCI World has a performance of +63% on the same period.

ETFs don't come for free - there must be enough market demand to warrant the creation of an ETF.  For large indexes such as MSCI World, an ETF creator must be able to own enough of the stocks to effectively replicate the index. You can't just "invest" in an index directly - you must replicate what the index measures somehow.
I also suspect that it could be very difficult to create a leveraged MSCI World ETF given the very large number of index constituents and the limited scope of derivatives and other mechanisms necessary to create leverage.
